# Regression on a Stratified Sample

Tags: regression, logistic, sampling, stratification

I am doing some regression analysis on a stratified sample where the stratification variable is the dependent variable. Do I need to adjust the regression or the results to account for the disproportionate subpopulations at all?

In other words, I have a sample containing groups **A** and **B** where **B** is very rare in the population but relatively common in the sample. Are the results of a regression on "Group" valid as they are, or do they need to be adjusted to reduce the effect of **B** members?

Comment: This sounds like a case-control study: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case%E2%80%93control_study . That link is a place to start to find out what is and is not possible with that design.

Comment: Do these links answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69561/case-control-study-and-logistic-regression and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67903/does-down-sampling-change-logistic-regression-coefficients/