# Logistic regression with probability of success close to one

Tags: regression, logistic, rare-events

Are there any caveats when logistic regression is used on a sample with average probability of success close to one (1.4M dataset, mean prob. of success = 0.975)?

Comment: How many predictors are you using?

Comment: 24, some of them are categorical with several levels

Comment: You need to check whether you're getting extreme bias in odds ratio estimates when some predictor patterns define very small groups.

Comment: For starters, what are the counts and # of successes of each category in each of those categorical variables?

Comment: It's a country-wide data, so one of the controlled variables included in the analysis is "region" with 80 levels, where number of cases varies hugely from 800 to 100000. But this variable is included as control only. The categorical variables that are the aim of analysis have 2 to 10 levels, with no less than 4000 cases per level.

Comment: So you've got 35,000 successes & say 250 degrees of freedom for the predictors, & no predictor patterns defining very small groups - I wouldn't be expecting any problems. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression/68917) for a problem that can happen & how to deal with it.

Comment: Posts [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67903/does-down-sampling-change-logistic-regression-coefficients) & 
[here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression) are relevant to the general question of balance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you seem to come from a social-science background, [King & Zeng (2001), "Logistic Regression in Rare Events Data", *Political Analysis*, **9**, pp 137–163](http://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/4125045/relogit%20rare%20events.pdf?s) might be a good starter - the term here is "rare event data".The authors claim that "popular statistical procedures, such as logistic regression, can sharply underestimate the probability of rare events", and the paper had quite some impact.

Comment: That nice paper shows how to estimate the bias in $\hat{\beta}$ in the rare event situation, but does not demonstrate that the bias-corrected estimator is closer to the true $\beta$, i.e., that the variance of the bias correction is small enough that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @julian: I added the full reference - it's often a good idea to do so because links "rot"