# Modeling data with logistic regression

Tags: logistic

I am new in statistical modeling and l am trying to model a financial data with logistic regression and I am facing a challenge here.

1. Some of the predictor variables have integer values( negative, zero and positive) in them. How to I treat them? In school professors dont use negative data values in teaching.
2. The dependent variable(binary) has about 97% of zeros and 3% of ones and I am modeling the case where the dependent variable is 1. 
   Since the zeros are so much, do I take a reasonable sample (like 2/3)of data so that the ratio of the ones to zeros will be say 1:3?

Comment: 2. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67903/does-down-sampling-change-logistic-regression-coefficients/68726). The only reason to do that would be constraints on computational resources.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the site.

Regarding 1) It shouldn't matter if the predictor variables are negative or positive.

Regarding 2) The key thing is usually whether the sample of DV = 1 is large enough, not whether it is much smaller than that of DV = 0.