# problems in doing logistic regression with unbalanced sample, give me some references

Tags: logistic, references, prediction, unbalanced-classes

I have a dataset with lots Y=0 and few Y=1. I have to run logistic regression, so I'm using a retrospective sample in order to get a more balanced sample.
Could someone give me some references that explain which are the problems arising when I use logistic regression in an unbalanced sample?
I kwow that the main problems are instability of estimated coefficients and poor predictive power of the model, but I need some references.

Comment: The problem is the few $Y=1$ rather than the many $Y=0$. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67903/does-down-sampling-change-logistic-regression-coefficients). If you *already have* the data, there's no benefit to throwing some of it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Logistic Regression in Rare Events Data](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/0s.pdf) in Political Analysis 9 (2001): 137-63 by Gary King and Langche Zeng.

There really isn't a problem using logistic regression modelling in the case you described.  The issues is that your estimates will have small-sample bias.  You can use exact logistic regression if your sample isn't too big or you can use the method described in the paper above which is based off of a penalized-likelihood approach.

Comment: But the magnitude of the problem is small, and ordinary maximum likelihood estimation may suffice.