# Is a predictive model biased if you sample 10,000 values from 2 significantly different populations?

Tags: predictive-models, sample-size, sample, bias, unbiased-estimator

Say you want to build a predictive model to classify two groups, Yellow cars VS Silver cars. There are over 1 million silver cars, but only 30,000 Yellow cars. Would a model be biased if you randomly sample 10,000 Silver cars and 10,000 yellow cars to build a training dataset? Would you need equal proportions of yellow to silver cars to reflect their true population in the universe of cars?

Comment: See [Does down-sampling change logistic regression coefficients?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/67903/17230).

Comment: Thanks Scortchi, I have a math background but had some difficultly following that post, pretty detailed statistics. Is that saying that the influence of downsampling is non-significant? Also that posts hints as computational restrictions, which I am facing (billions of records in my case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the algorithm used to build the predictive model does not allow for a weighted sample as input, the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks piccolbo, would you suggest Probability-proportional-to-size sampling? I'm reading this wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)