# Case Control Sampling in Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, classification, unbalanced-classes, case-control-study

In [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GavRXXEHGqU) by Hastie and Tibshirani, it is mentioned that with case-control samples, we can estimate the logistic regression parameters accurately, but the intercept term is incorrect. It also gives a formula to correct the intercept term.

Could you please mathematically explain why this happens?

Additionally, could you please explain why exactly case-control sampling is necessary, and which methods of classification are particularly sensitive to imbalanced priors?

Comment: We have no access to that lecture, so it is hard to comment. However, I would not say that the constant is incorrect, I would say it is of little substantive interest as it represents the design rather than an empirical estimate of the prevalence of the event.

Comment: Thanks @MaartenBuis for your reply. I have edited the link to the lecture, should be accessible now. Anyway, can you please explain why changing the case-control ratio would only affect the constant and not the other regression parameters?

Comment: Do you understand what a case control study is?  After Trevor Hastie discussed the logistic regression model, Rob Tibshirani interrupted and gave a great explanation of what a case control study is and why it is often practical when a prospective study is not.  Trevor qualified what he said mentioning "if the model is correct".  Unfortunately I do not follow why the intercept should be 0 but a transformation corrects it.

Comment: Logistic regression is so widely used because of its link function, logit. For a binary outcome, this has attractive properties, among which its unbiasedness under different sampling scheme including case-control. Please find the reasoning here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296320/during-oversampling-of-rare-events-why-are-the-beta-coefficients-of-the-indepen/297903#297903

Comment: [Scortchi's answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/68726/1352) points to a reference.